# re-organizing the contents a text file in python3

Tags: pandas, file

I have a tab separated file like this small example:

small example:

```
PB.5680.1   GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9773
PB.5681.1   GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9825,GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9097,GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9835,GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9415,GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9259,GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9539
PB.5686.1   GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9151,GS_Isoseq_HQ_transcript/9450
```

I am trying to parse the file and make a new file like the following expected output. in fact every transcript/number should be in a separate line but if they are from the same line in the input file, they would have similar first column:

expected output:

```
PB.5680.1   transcript/9773
PB.5681.1   transcript/9825
PB.5681.1   transcript/9097
PB.5681.1   transcript/9835
PB.5681.1   transcript/9415
PB.5681.1   transcript/9259
PB.5681.1   transcript/9539
PB.5686.1   transcript/9151
PB.5686.1   transcript/9450
```

to do so, I wrote the following piece of code in `python3`.

```
import pandas as pd
df =  pd.read_csv('myfile.txt',  sep='\t,_', engine='python')
column = []
for line in df:
    dat = column.append(line)
    dat.to_csv("outfile.txt", sep = "\t")
```

but it does not return what I am trying to get. do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

We're going to give the columns with PB.5680.1 the name ID and the other column will be called TRANSCRIPT for easiness sake.

I'm also going to assume that the values in the TRANSCRIPT column are all strings. So we need to make each row a list first, the explode the list, and finally export it.

```
#Making TRANSCRIPT values lists
df['TRANSCRIPT']= df['TRANSCRIPT'].apply(lambda x: x.split(','))

#Set index to ID and explode TRANSCRIPT
df2 = df.set_index('ID')['TRANSCRIPT'].explode()

#export to CSV
df2.to_csv('./allDone.csv', header = False)
```